# Getting image to display after hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am working on a slideout nav screen. I got the horizontal slide out menu to work perfectly without media queries, but when I tried to add my slide out navigation menu to my normal navigation menu, I cannot get the three line hamburger menu image to display when in a media screen on `max-width: 640px;`. I hide the `nav-btn` (menu image) when the normal navigation menu is displaying, but I want the `nav-btn` to display when I get to the smaller screen size to allow me to open the menu.

Does anyone see why my nav-btn will not display within my media query?

```js
 //open the lateral panel
 $('.nav-btn').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.nav-panel').addClass('is-visible');
 });
 //clode the lateral panel
 $('.nav-panel').on('click', function(event){
  if( $(event.target).is('.nav-panel') || $(event.target).is('.nav-panel-close') ) { 
   $('.nav-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 });
```

```css
.nav_list {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}
.nav_list > a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 25px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_list > a > li {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45a5ba;
}
.nav_list > a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #CCC;
}
.nav-btn {
     display: none;
}
/*.nav-panel {
  display: none;
 }*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
 .header {
  display: none;
 }
 .nav-panel {
  display: block;
 }
 .nav_list {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}
.nav_list > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 15px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 /*border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;*/
}
.nav_list > a > li {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45a5ba;
}
.nav_list > a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #CCC;
}
.nav-btn {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 right: 2%;
 top: 3%;
}
.nav-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 1s;
  transition: visibility 1s;
}
.nav-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
  transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;
}
.nav-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.nav-panel.is-visible::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.nav-panel.is-visible .nav-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.nav-panel.is-visible .nav-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.nav-panel-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.96);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0s;
  transition: top 0.3s 0s;
}
#nav-slide-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #45a5ba;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
.from-right .nav-panel-header, .from-left .nav-panel-header {
  top: -50px;
}
.from-right .nav-panel-header {
  right: 0;
}
.from-left .nav-panel-header {
  left: 0;
}
.is-visible .nav-panel-header {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s 0.3s;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
   <div class="logo">Optimum Designs</div>
   <nav>
 <a href="#0" class="nav-btn"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/mobile_menu_bttn.png" style="height: 28px; width: 28px;"></a>
    <!-- <span class="nav-btn"></span> -->
    <ul class="nav_list">
     <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Work</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Approach</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Company</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Services</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main class="cd-main-content">
  <h1>Slide In Panel</h1>
 </main>

 <div class="nav-panel from-right">

  <header class="nav-panel-header">
   <div id="nav-slide-title">Menu</div>
   <a href="#0" class="nav-panel-close">Close</a>
  </header>

  <div class="nav-panel-container">
   <div class="nav-panel-content">
    <ul class="nav_list">
     <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Work</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Approach</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Company</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Services</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
   </div> <!-- nav-panel-content -->
  </div> <!-- nav-panel-container -->
 </div> <!-- nav-panel -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the `nav-btn` within my `header` div. I was doing this `.header {display: none;}` which was not allowing my button to show within my media query.

For those that looked, thanks.